# update with subselect/how to select time greater than 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the image below. I am new to sql syntax and I have the following update statement with a subselect. I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this but this is what I have.

What I want to do is check the `LastRestartTime` and if it is greater than 24 hours `RestartInterval`, then update restart time to current time.

I have an exe that will check the table for `LastRestartTime` and if `Active=1 and RestartInterval >=24`, it will kill and restart (or just start the process if it was stopped) the process.

I then want the program to update the `LastRestarttime` to that current time.

I'm not sure how to do this.

```
update any_table.dbo.thisDatabase 
set LastRestartTime = GetDate() 
where ProcessName In (Select ProcessName 
                      from any_table.dbo.thisDatabase 
                      where LastRestartTime > 24);
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this question is relevant to C#. Removed tag.

Comment: Its relevant to c# because that is what I am writing my program in

Comment: webby, why did you roll back my formatting? and now you've rolled back @marc's tag edit....

Comment: because you are not offering anything constructive and your formatting didn't make sense for most parts.  You removed the Microsoft tag when it is Microsoft SQL server I am using, for example

Comment: You need to have properly formatted questions if you want to receive help and SQL Server implies Microsoft.  When posting code, it should be formatted as such.

Comment: Not when you do a search MySQL comes up in a search as well.  I want to narrow it down for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a subquery, try:

```
UPDATE any_table.dbo.thisDatabase 
SET LastRestartTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE LastRestartTime <= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Missing comma after 24.

Comment: Thank you, this is more appropriate.  I am just learning, and I wasn't aware of the current_timestamp and dateadd options available

Comment: Not a problem. There's also a `DATEDIFF` function but I can never remember how the rounding works (i.e. does 23.75 hours difference round up to 24 or down to 23) so I always use `DATEADD`

Comment: This where statement doesn't look [Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  Shouldn't it be `WHERE LastRestartTime <= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: ErikPhilips, I'd never even thought about that before, thanks for the info. Updated answer with your improvement. @webby68, worth taking note of that change.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, still learning, I guess I don't understand why I would write the sql code to <= DATEADD(HOUR -24, CurrentTimestamp) when I want it to set LastRestartTime only if it is over 24 hours

Comment: If you do `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 24 hours` (which is what the `DATEADD` is doing) you get the time 24 hours ago, then you want to find all records where the `LastRestartTime` is equal to or earlier than that. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, now I get it.  The problem I have is that it updates all the rows rather than just the one that is past 24.  So I added and RestartIfRunning=1; at the end of the WHERE clause, so now the update statement is as follows, but no rows are affected.

Comment: UPDATE any_table.dbo.thisDatabase 
SET LastRestartTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE LastRestartTime <= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and RestartIfRunning=1;

Comment: In the screenshot all your RestartIfRunnings are NULL. You might want to add the `Active=1 and RestartInterval >=24` from your question to it. It appears to work as intended on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7deb7/1) but I'm not sure of your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I did add 1 to RestartIfRunning since that screenshot.